# Tensorflow Set Graph/Session Context on Class Method Call

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, keras

I am running two tensorflow models in parallel.  Each has its own graph and session.

To ensure there are no graph/op conflicts I have created a wrapper class that maintains the two models' respective graph and session:

```
class ModelWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = None
        self.sess = None
        self.model = None

    def load_model(self, pth_model=None):
        # load graph, session, and model here
```

On call I then set the context using `with`:

```
    def predict(self, np_x):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            with self.sess.as_default():
                np_y_preds = self.model.predict(np_x)
        return np_y_preds
```

Is there a more elegant way to set the context every time I call the `predict` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use python decorators to wrap the first two lines inside methods like your predict method like described [here](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/) for variable scopes. That would be the same code though, just nicer to look at and very handy when having multiple such methods.

I don't know if you would consider that more elegant, but I personally prefer to simply do calls on the session object directly, instead of using a `with self.sess.as_default():` control-flow structure.